# How to get chat history of a selected user in XMPP

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp

I am new to xmpp , i need to store and show the chat history of users . i am getting the full history while using the below code.I only need the chat history of the selected user.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *xmppMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage=[XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [xmppMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *messageEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    fetchRequest.entity = messageEntity;

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:YES];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    [self print:[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:results]];
```

How can i get the chat history of a particular user,. i have searched a lot but couldnt got a success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)loadChatHistoryWithUserName:(NSString *)userName
{
    NSString *userJid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",userName,self.hostName];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [_xmppMsgStorage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *predicateFrmt = @"bareJidStr == %@";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFrmt, userJid];
    request.predicate = predicate;
    NSArray *messages = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. it worked for me , my jid string was wrong at first. thanks a lot

Comment: @suhail kalathil Its working fine but the problem  I am facing is that I am not getting the latest message (Recent one).

Comment: How to Fetch Chat history with XEP-0313?